# Store HttpResponse in dictionary

Tags: python, django

I have a trouble with long calculations in django. I am not able to install Celery because of idiocy of my company, so I have to "reinvent the wheel".
I am trying to make all calculations in TaskQueue class, which stores all calculations in dictionary "results". Also, I am trying to make "Please Wait" page, which will asks this TaskQueue if task with provided key is ready.
And the problem is that the results somehow disappear.
I have some view with long calculations.

```
def some_view(request):
    ...
    uuid = task_queue.add_task(method_name, params) #method_name(params) returns HttpResponse
    return redirect('/please_wait/?uuid={0}'.format(uuid))
```

And please_wait view:

```
def please_wait(request):
    uuid = request.GET.get('uuid','0')
    ready = task_queue.task_ready(uuid)
    if ready:
        return task_queue.task_result(uuid)
    elif ready == None:
        return render_to_response('admin/please_wait.html',{'not_found':True})
    else:
        return render_to_response('admin/please_wait.html',{'not_found':False})
```

And last code, my TaskQueue:

```
class TaskQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = ThreadPool()
        self.results = {}
        self.lock = Lock()

    def add_task(self, method, params):
        self.lock.acquire()
        new_uuid = self.generate_new_uuid()
        while self.results.has_key(new_uuid):
            new_uuid = self.generate_new_uuid()
        self.results[new_uuid] = self.pool.apply_async(func=method, args=params)
        self.lock.release()
        return new_uuid

    def generate_new_uuid(self):
        return uuid.uuid1().hex[0:8]

    def task_ready(self, task_id):
        if self.results.has_key(task_id):
            return self.results[task_id].ready()
        else:
            return None

    def task_result(self, task_id):
        if self.task_ready(task_id):
            return self.results[task_id].get()
        else:
            return None
global task_queue = TaskQueue()
```

After task addition I could log result providing it's uuid for some seconds, and then it says that task doesn't ready. Here is my log: (I am outputting task_queue.results)

```
[INFO] 2013-10-01 16:04:52,782 logger: {'ade5d154': <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x1989906c>}
[INFO] 2013-10-01 16:05:05,740 logger: {}
```

Help me, please! Why the hell result disappears?

**UPD**: @freakish helped me to find out some new information. This result doesn't disappear forever, it disappears sometimes if I will repeat my tries to log it.

```
[INFO] 2013-10-01 16:52:41,743 logger: {}
[INFO] 2013-10-01 16:52:45,775 logger: {}
[INFO] 2013-10-01 16:52:48,855 logger: {'ade5d154': <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x1989906c>}
```

Comment: Are you running this on the dev server, or in production?

Comment: @daniel-roseman I am running this on dev server.

Comment: @Geslot I've tried your code and it works as expected. So what can happen is the following: 1) you actually delete keys somewhere 2) you are running multiple Django processes (`task_queue` won't be shared between them) 3) you are overriding `task_queue`: this `global` flag is intriguing, are you running this inside a function? Maybe you call it multiple times?

Comment: @freakish seems that you are right. Look at the end of my question, I've updated it. Actually, I am running 4 processes.

Comment: I'm not familiarized with multiprocessing module, however it seems that the problem is you are using a thread local Lock implementation. In my company I have a similar problem (not able to use Celery) and I use a PosixLock (I really know this is an ugly solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so we've established that you are running 4 processes of Django. In that case your queue won't be shared between them. Actually there are two possible solutions AFAIK:

1. Use a shared queueing server. You can write your own (see for example [this entry](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager)) but using a proper one (like Celery) will be a lot easier (if you can't convince your employer to install it, then quit the job ;)).
2. Use database to store results inside it and let each server do the calculations (via processes or threads). It does not have to be a proper database server. You can use [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for example. This is more secure and reliable way but less efficient. I think this is easier then queueing mechanism. You simply create table with columns: `id, state, result`. When you create job you update entry with `state=processing`, when you finish the job you update entry with `state=done` and `result=result` (for example as JSON string). This is easy and reliable (you actually don't need a queue here at all, the order of jobs doesn't matter unless I'm missing something).

Of course you won't be able to use this `.ready()` functions with it (you should store results inside these storages) unless you pickle results but that is an unnecessary overhead.